# Mac numpad keypad works as directional pad

Tags: keyboard-layout, macintosh

I have a keyboard with an Apple/Mac layout (Option and Command instead of Alt and Windows keys), but I can't get its number keypad to work. I was able to figure out that the number keys are being used as a directional pad (4 as left, 6 as right, etc.) I found some advice online to press fn+F6 twice to change the numpad's behavior but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out and thought I'd save someone else the trouble.

**The <kbd>clear</kbd> key** in the numpad (in the top left) functions as a numlock on this keyboard (the key that regulates how the numpad functions). Press the key to toggle between the numpad's two functions (as numpad and as directional pad).

Comment: Actually, it **is** the numlock key, from the keyswitch on downwards.  The USB code that is sent over the wire is the `NumLock` code.  The differences lie in (a) what is engraved on the keytop and (b) how Apple operating systems interpret that keycode.

Comment: The key functions as "clear" on OS X so it's likely that the key default "numlock" function as it would be on any other keyboard. (If the keyboard was recognized properly, there would be no numlock toggle.)